# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. - Google Cloud Function, Vue3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to make a web scraper using Google Cloud Functions. The GCF works as expected when fed input on the GCF test function area, however when triggering the GCF with an HTTP request from my clientside (coded in Vue3), I am getting the following CORS error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

This is my HTTP request from the client-side,

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ input }),
        });
        // console.log(response);
        const data = await response.json();
```

GCF Code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

exports.webScrape = async (req, resp) => {
    resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    resp.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"
    );
    const input = req.body.input;
    async function scrapeSite(url) {
        //it does stuff here
    }
    try {
        const response = await scrapeSite(input);
        const data = await JSON.stringify(response);
        resp.send(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("server is catching the error");
        console.log(error);
        resp.status(404).send({
            ErrorMessage: "An invalid URL was given to the input box, please check the input and try again",
            error,
        });
    }
    return;
};
```

Comment: Can you share your Cloud function's code ?

Comment: Your serverless function should return HTTP status 200 for all HTTP methods, including OPTIONS.

Comment: Shared my cloud function's code.

Comment: When  I send the data here I need to specify the status as well?

Comment: You should not do `return;`at the end. An HTTPS Cloud Function shall be terminated by `send()` or `end()`.

Comment: OK, though is the cloud function not being terminated when it sends the data in resp.send(data)?

Comment: Please check if the [following sample page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples) helps you?

Comment: I need to update this, it works! Sorry for the delay.

Comment: If it already works then can you please post it as an answer for visibility?